# Mounting an `existing` EFS to an ECS Task returns error `Failed to resolve "fs-id"`

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, amazon-efs

hope to find you well. I am trying to experiment with the scenario I had to tear down my cluster and rebuild it.
However, since this is a production set up, I want to retain the EFS and mount it again if it already exists.

This is my CDK code:

```
const config = this.node.tryGetContext('stages')[props.STAGE]

        /*  Cluster  */

        const qlashMainCluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, `qlashMainCluster`, {
            vpc: props.vpc,
            clusterName: `${props.STAGE}_QlashMainCluster`,
            enableFargateCapacityProviders: true,            
            defaultCloudMapNamespace: {
                name: `${props.STAGE}qlashMainCluster`,
                vpc: props.vpc,
                useForServiceConnect: true
            }
        })

        // EFS

        const qmmTasksEfsSecurityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'qmmTasksEfsSecurityGroup', {
            vpc: props.vpc,
            securityGroupName: 'qmmTasksEfsSecurityGroup'
        })

        let qmmTasksEfs: efs.IFileSystem

        if (!config.QlashMainClusterEFSID) {
            qmmTasksEfs = new efs.FileSystem(this, `${props.STAGE}qmmTasksEfs`, {
                fileSystemName: `${props.STAGE}qmmTasksEfs`,
                vpc: props.vpc,
                removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.RETAIN,
                securityGroup: qmmTasksEfsSecurityGroup,
                encrypted: true,
                lifecyclePolicy: efs.LifecyclePolicy.AFTER_30_DAYS,
                enableAutomaticBackups: true
            })

            new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'QlashMainClusterEFSID', {
                exportName: 'QlashMainClusterEFSID',
                value: qmmTasksEfs.fileSystemId
            })
            
        } else {
            qmmTasksEfs = efs.FileSystem.fromFileSystemAttributes(this, `${props.STAGE}qmmTasksEfs`, {
                securityGroup: qmmTasksEfsSecurityGroup,
                fileSystemId: config.QlashMainClusterEFSID
            })
        }

        const qmmRedisEfsAccessPoint = new efs.AccessPoint(this, `${props.STAGE}qmmRedisAccessPoint`, {
            fileSystem: qmmTasksEfs,
            path: '/redis',
            createAcl: {
                ownerGid: '1001',
                ownerUid: '1001',
                permissions: '750'
            },
            posixUser: {
                uid: '1001',
                gid: '1001'
            }
        })

        const qmmMongoEfsAccessPoint = new efs.AccessPoint(this, `${props.STAGE}qmmMongoAccessPoint`, {
            fileSystem: qmmTasksEfs,
            path: '/mongodb',
            createAcl: {
                ownerGid: '1002',
                ownerUid: '1002',
                permissions: '750'
            },
            posixUser: {
                uid: '1002',
                gid: '1002'
            }
        })

        // Redis

        const qmmRedisServiceSecurityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'qmmRedisSecurityGroup', {
            vpc: props.vpc,
            securityGroupName: 'qmmRedisSecurityGroup'
        })

        qmmTasksEfsSecurityGroup.addIngressRule(
            ec2.Peer.securityGroupId(qmmRedisServiceSecurityGroup.securityGroupId),
            ec2.Port.tcp(2049),
            'Allow inbound traffic from qmm_redis to qmmTasksEfs'
        )

        if (props.qlashMainInstanceSecurityGroup) {
            qmmRedisServiceSecurityGroup.addIngressRule(
                ec2.Peer.securityGroupId(props.qlashMainInstanceSecurityGroup.securityGroupId),
                ec2.Port.tcp(6379),
                'Allow inbound traffic to qmm_redis from qmmMain instance'
            )
        }

        qmmRedisServiceSecurityGroup.addIngressRule(
            ec2.Peer.ipv4(props.vpc.vpcCidrBlock),
            ec2.Port.tcp(6379),
            'Allow inbound traffic to qmm_redis from resources in qlashMainClusterVpc'
        )

        const qmmRedisTaskDefinition = new ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(this, `${props.STAGE.toLowerCase()}qmmRedisTask`, {
            cpu: 512,
            memoryLimitMiB: 1024,
            volumes: [
                {
                    name: `${props.STAGE.toLowerCase()}_qmm_redis_volume`,
                    efsVolumeConfiguration: {
                        fileSystemId: qmmTasksEfs.fileSystemId,
                        transitEncryption: 'ENABLED',
                        authorizationConfig: {
                            accessPointId: qmmRedisEfsAccessPoint.accessPointId,
                            iam: 'ENABLED'
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        })

        qmmRedisTaskDefinition.addToTaskRolePolicy(
            new iam.PolicyStatement({
                actions: [
                    'elasticfilesystem:*',
                    'elasticfilesystem:ClientWrite',
                    'elasticfilesystem:ClientMount',
                    'elasticfilesystem:ClientRootAccess',
                    'elasticfilesystem:DescribeMountTargets',
                    'elasticfilesystem:CreateAccessPoint',
                    'elasticfilesystem:DeleteAccessPoint',
                    'elasticfilesystem:DescribeAccessPoints',
                    'elasticfilesystem:DescribeFileSystems'
                ],
                resources: [qmmTasksEfs.fileSystemArn],
            })
        )

        qmmRedisTaskDefinition.addToTaskRolePolicy(
            new iam.PolicyStatement({
                actions: ['ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones'],
                resources: ['*']
            })
        )

        const qmmRedisContainer = qmmRedisTaskDefinition.addContainer(`${props.STAGE.toLowerCase()}_qmm_redis`, {
            image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromAsset('./resources/cluster-resources/redis'),
            containerName: `${props.STAGE.toLowerCase()}_qmm_redis`,
            portMappings: [{ containerPort: 6379, name: `${props.STAGE.toLowerCase()}_qmm_redis` }],
            healthCheck: {
                command: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "-h", "localhost", "-p", "6379", "ping"],
                interval: cdk.Duration.seconds(20),
                timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(20),
                retries: 5
            },
            logging: ecs.LogDriver.awsLogs({streamPrefix: `${props.STAGE.toLowerCase()}_qmm_redis`}),
            command: ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
        })

        qmmRedisContainer.addMountPoints({
            sourceVolume: `${props.STAGE.toLowerCase()}_qmm_redis_volume`,
            containerPath: '/redis/data',
            readOnly: false
        })

        const qmmRedisService = new ecs.FargateService(this, `${props.STAGE}qmmRedisService`, {
            serviceName: `${props.STAGE}_qmmRedisService`,
            cluster: qlashMainCluster,
            desiredCount: 1,
            securityGroups: [qmmRedisServiceSecurityGroup],
            taskDefinition: qmmRedisTaskDefinition,
            enableExecuteCommand: true,
            vpcSubnets: {
                subnetGroupName: props.qmmRedisSubnetGroupName
            },
            serviceConnectConfiguration: {
                services: [{ portMappingName: `${props.STAGE.toLowerCase()}_qmm_redis` }]
            }
        })
```

What is quirky,is that everything works just fine at the first creation of the stack (when the EFS is created), but when I try to mount it again (as I recreate the stack) it returns the error:

```
ResourceInitializationError: failed to invoke EFS utils commands to set up EFS volumes: stderr: Failed to resolve "fs-022089502ea31e256.efs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com" - check that your file system ID is correct, and ensure that the VPC has an EFS mount target for this file system ID.
```

As you can see from the code, the mount target exists, and as far as I can tell, they get passed on to the old EFS when I launch the stack, isn't it right?

Also, I highly doubt it is an EFS IAM permissions issue, because I am temporarily launching the same stack with all the permissions for EFS.

Lastly, I've checked other issues here in StackOverflow (
[AWS ECS (Fargate) is failing to mount EFS file system "Failed to resolve"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65550544/aws-ecs-fargate-is-failing-to-mount-efs-file-system-failed-to-resolve)
[Issue with mounting EFS access point from an AWS ECS Fargate task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73863395/issue-with-mounting-efs-access-point-from-an-aws-ecs-fargate-task)
[EFS mount in ECS "Failed to resolve"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70453008/efs-mount-in-ecs-failed-to-resolve)
) which point to ensure that the VPC has 'DNS hostnames' and 'DNS resolution' enabled, which **is the case for me**.

If you have any ideas or suggestion it would be much appreciated, in the meantime I wish you a wonderful day :)